# React 18.1.0 Dependency Tree Errors- can't resolve dependency tree

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, dependencies, dependency-tree

I am currently having trouble solving dependency tree error with React 18. Initially, I couldn't start a new react project with npx-create-react-app my-app (a template was not provided). I fixed that and can now start a new project, but I have two other react apps that I cannot get to start up.

The first one is a portfolio react template that I downloaded. I opened it up and ran npm start in the terminal with no luck (attached is the dependency tree error message).

These are the steps I took to try to fix it:

1. I deleted all react and node folders that were dowloaded on my Mac (outside of the directory).
2. Ran npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
3. Ran rm -rf node_modules
4. Ran npm cach clean --force
5. I removed package.lock.json
6. I changed these scripts in package.json to updated versions
   nodemon: 2.0.16
   react: 18.1.0
   react-scripts: 5.0.1
   React-dom: 18.1.0

When I then run npm start I get the dependency errors. I would appreciate any help and advice! Thanks so much![!dependency errors]